# Capturing And Sending Video on Java with Jitsi Library

Tags: java, video-capture

I'm trying to develop a video chat app on java. I found `libjitsi`, it uses native libraries. There are two example codes which called `AVTransmit2` and `AVReceive2` (if you want to look: https://jitsi.org/Projects/LibJitsi). But i can't run any of them. I think I don't know how to add native libraries. When i link the native libraries with that:

`System.load("the path of the native library")`

all of them seems added except one. The one which stops the running with linking error, the one which called `AWTrenderer` needs links for more libraries. But `libjitsi` gives me enough libraries for run the code i think. But i still getting linking problem at output. So where is the problem? Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I didn't use system.load for linking the native libraries. My IDE's (eclipse) got a configuration for it. You just selecting the folder which includes native libraries.